# Multiple domains on single Nuxt app deplyed on Vercel

Tags: url, dns, nuxt.js, single-page-application, vercel

I've an **Nuxt** app, deployed on **Vercel**, *xpto.vercel.app* with specific client routes:

- xpto.vercel.app/client-a
- xpto.vercel.app/client-b
- xpto.vercel.app/admin

I have 3 domains, I don't know if this is possible, but there is any way to point each domain to that client specific route? (with only one project on vercel)

```
www.client-a.com => xpto.vercel.app/client-a
www.client-b.com => xpto.vercel.app/client-b
www.app-admin.com => xpto.vercel.app/admin
```

This is my current solution, but it's far from ideal, and requires FTP.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**index.php**

```php
<?php

$project = "client-a";
$url = "https://xpto.vercel.app/" . $project . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Vercel Support:

> Thank you for reaching out to Vercel Support.
>
> Unfortunately, this is not possible in a single Vercel project.
>
> Let us know if you have any further questions or concerns.